# jQuery DatePicker on Focus

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am trying to show my datepicker on focus the textfield, this is what I have:

```
 <%--importing jQuery for datepicker--%>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//jquery-formatcurrency.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/jquery.formatCurrency.js">‌​</script>

 <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
           <label id="ReportFromLabel" runat="server">Report From Date:</label>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
           <asp:TextBox ID="ReportFrom" name="ReportFrom" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
       </asp:TableCell>
 </asp:TableRow>


 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        <%--date jQuery--%>
        $("#ReportFrom").datepicker({
            showOn: "focus"
        });
    });

</script>
```

It is at the moment doing nothing.... am I missing something? or just completely overlooking a blatant error?

Comment: That's the default behavior of jQuery Datepicker.

Comment: To do nothing? Even though I have it showing on focus....

Comment: The `showOn: "focus"` is default. Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: No I dont, I have no errors. Does any of it need to be in special tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("[id$=ReportFrom]").datepicker({

    });
});
```

**Try this**

Comment: Why does this work better than the `#ReportFrom` selector? Is ASP.net adding something to the ID so that doesn't match?